# how to add extra cost to shipping flat cost according to delivery date in opencart

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I want to add an extra shipping cost when a user selects today's date how can i do this in opencart , please point me to the file which set's the delivery cost or where is the following session variable set.

```
   $this->session->data['shipping_method']['cost']
```

Suraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an extensions that uses PHP functions getdate()? In order to track the last 24 hours being true or not? Or is there an extension that adds an extra variable?

To answer your question "please point me to the file which these arrays are being sent:" These commands look like controller syntax for sending arrays. So whatever file path you found this code look in the same paths but model or view. Example

view:

```
catalog/view/theme/*/template/account/shipping.tpl
```

or controller

```
 catalog/controller/account/customerpartner/shipping.php // probably where you found this code...
```

or lastly model:

```
 catalog/model/account/shipping.php'
```

in there you will be able to find